# Why do I sometimes get no rows when perfoming a SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have a SQL table that is full of data. I am using the following code to extract column values and put them into an array. This works fine as when I do `var_dump(array)`, I get the elements in the array printed out, and they look correct. However, sometimes I just get empty elements. This basically means that the column values were not obtained. Does anyone know why I sometimes get no results when the table is full of records?

```
$names = array();
$dob = array();
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx")or die("Error");
mysql_select_db("details")or die("Error");
$query="SELECT * FROM members";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
$names[] = $row["name"];
$dob[] = $row["dob"];
}
var_dump($names);
var_dump($dob);
```

Comment: `sometimes`..... when is that `sometimes`? on what occasion it happens?

Comment: By sometimes I refer to a random occasion I run the script. For example, 1 in 3 times it would happen

Comment: does this page contains only this code or other codes too?

Comment: This is the code under an if statement (if a button is pressed). So it is the only relevant code.

Comment: my guess is, some fatal error happens before this code but as probably error reporting is suppressed, it gets only blank. Its a very wild guess though.